# Using CAST function in ArcMap with ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I would like to use the CAST function in the definition query property of a layer and/or in the label class sql query window.

This was the most promising [link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/55649-Using-SQL-CAST-functionality-in-against-a-File-Geodatabase) that I've found, including the two links found there.

I haven't tried whether the syntax showed works against a file gdb but it doesn't work on SDE.

Anyone have luck using sql in ArcMap 10 against ArcSDE 10?  Thanks.

---

This worked on sde when the field is a Double.

CAST(MP AS CHARACTER(12)) LIKE '7%'

It does work but '%5' doesn't work.  Having the percent after works and before doesn't.

Comment: You may want to post your current syntax so we can pick it apart and look for errors. For example, file geodatabases use quotes around field names, personal geodatabases use brackets, and SDE doesn't use anything around field names.

Comment: What is the underlying DBMS?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a SQL Server instance to test with but try the [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933238%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or [RIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238425%28v=sql.80%29) functions, e.g.:

To get the first character:

```
LEFT(CAST(MP AS CHARACTER(12)), 1) = '7'
```

To get the last character:

```
RIGHT(CAST(MP AS CHARACTER(12)), 1) = '7'
```